# Do something while sem_wait in C

Tags: c, while-loop, posix, semaphore

I am trying to avoid using sem_wait, and have something like:
"While waiting for semaphore, do something".
So then I found out about sem_getvalue which is supposed to return 0 in case of success.

So I initiate the semaphore with:

```
sem_init(&sem1, 0, 0);
```

And instead of

```
sem_wait(&sem1);
```

I need something like:

```
while(sem_getvalue(&sem1, 2) < 0){
    printf("do this\n");
}
```

I have no problems with sem_wait, everything seems to function properly.
But with the second, I am getting Segmentation fault error during execution.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should look at `sem_trywait` function: http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use `sem_getvalue` for this since you are losing atomicity. Use `sem_trywait` for the task

```
for (;;) {
  if (sem_trywait(&sem1)) {
     if (errno != EAGAIN) {
         /* handle error */
         abort();
     }
     errno = 0;
     printf("do this\n");
  } else {
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @JustinIurman, unfortunately it had been a bit wrong, because the `sem` functions don't return the error code directly, should even be better, now.

Comment: I didn't look deeper in your code, i was talking about the `sem_trywait` idea instead of using `sem_getvalue` (your answer should be the one validated anyway)

Comment: I had to think about it for a while but you're right, the OP says he wants to wait but still be able to do something between the checks. In that case `sem_trywait()` or `sem_timedwait()` is the answer, depending on the situation. The answer from dasblinkenlight covers the issue in the call itself, so it's still useful. I'll delete mine as its already covered in his.

Comment: Yes, now I am noticing some issues with sem_getvalue... Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

[`sem_getvalue`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_getvalue) returns a status, and places the semaphore value at the pointer passed as the second parameter. You need to check the return status (which is zero when the function succeeds) and only then check the semaphore value, like this:

```
int sval1;
if (sem_getvalue(&sem1, &sval1) == 0 && sval1 < 0) {
    ...
}
```